# GoogleMapsv2 API Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to run simple application with GoogleMaps API on Android. I've followed all steps to install correctly GooglePlayService SDK. When I execute "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()" it returns SUCCESS.
I've installed GoogleMaps APIv2, get my SHA1 key and create an API KEY but when I try to compile the sample "maps" the screen it's always blank with zooms buttons (+ and -).

I compile on a tablet with Android 4.0.4.
In my logcat I've first this :

```
I/Google Maps Android API(5165): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
```

And few seconds later :

```
E/Google Maps Android API(4885): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I suppose my API KEY for GoogleMaps API is wrong but I've created another and it always same result. Someone can maybe test my API KEY if I send it in private.

Thank you for your help !

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.mapdemo;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

/**
 * This shows how to create a simple activity with a map and a marker on the map.
 * <p>
 * Notice how we deal with the possibility that the Google Play services APK is not
 * installed/enabled/updated on a user's device.
 */
public class BasicMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
     */
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not have been
     * completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be stopped or
     * paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this method in
     * {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So which service did you enable in Google API console?

Comment: I've enable Google Maps Android API v2 in my console.

Comment: Have you add permission for network state in ur manifest file??

Comment: In fact, I try to compile the sample 'maps' by Google, so permissions are good, I've MAPS_RECEIVE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET, READ_GSERVICES, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION & ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: Ok....and Permission for use library of google map add in manifest file??

Comment: I miss it, I add this:
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> chil of <application> ?
But don't resolved :/

Comment: Ok....So finally check that the class name of your fragment for your map are the same as you are creating a object for GoogleMap in your java class??

Comment: My java class 'BasicMapActivity' is : package com.example.mapdemo;
But in my XML : class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
What I've to modify ?

Comment: Can you post your java class file?

Comment: I've added in my first post ;)

Comment: ok...this all is perfect....And i hope that you don't miss add your api key in manifest file?

Comment: I add the API KEY in manifest yes ;)
But I can't verify it... Maybe can you try my API KEY to verify it ?

Comment: But it should be your own api key

Comment: Yes you've right. I've remove debug.keystore in my Eclipse folder. The Eclipse creates me an new certificate. I copy/paste the SHA1 and add my package name to create the API KEY... All seems good but I've always blank screen =(